# Error Compiling Netty latest (Master) version - Unit test error

Tags: netty

When compiling latest Netty source from github I'm getting the following unit test error

> Running io.netty.handler.ssl.OioNioSocketSslEchoTest UNKNOWN SERVER
>   CERTIFICATE: CN=securechat.example.netty.gleamynode.net,
>   OU=Contributors, O=The Netty Project, L=Seongnam-si, ST=Kyunggi-do,
>   C=KR Jan 13, 2012 9:44:09 AM
>   io.netty.handler.ssl.AbstractSocketSslEchoTest WARNING: Unexpected
>   exception from the client side java.net.SocketException: Software
>   caused connection abort: recv failed
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:182)
>           at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:66)
>           at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:122)
>           at io.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioWorker.run(OioWorker.java:79)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.092 sec <<<
>   FAILURE!

and the Result is:

> Results :
>
> Tests in error:
>   testSslEcho(io.netty.handler.ssl.NioOioSocketSslEchoTest): An
>   established connection was aborted by the software in your host
>   machine   testSslEcho(io.netty.handler.ssl.OioNioSocketSslEchoTest):
>   Software caused connection abort: recv failed
>
> Tests run: 1421, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0
>
> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 1:19.163s [INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 13 09:44:10
>
> ---

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run the compile a few times and let us know if the problem persist ? Also it would be good to know the OS and java version.

Comment: Run it few time same results. OS = Win 2007 SDK=1.6_0_30

Comment: For now I disable the @test annotation in the SSL AbstractSocketSslEchoTest and compilation worked. However there is still an issue with this unit test which still need to be resolved.